# Is here simple way to convert Set into Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I tried:

```
  const state =  new Set( [5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 45, 60] );
  let preset = Object.assign( {}, state );
  console.log(preset)
  // {}
```

and got empty object. Also I tried to convert state to string and also failed:

```
state.values().toLocaleString()
// "[object Set Iterator]"
```

Or the only way is to iterate Set one by one?

Update: It should be an Array of values: [5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 45, 60] as a result.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: What keys are you expecting in the output?

Comment: Nina Scholz, CertainPerformance - I made update in the post.

Comment: Your expected output is invalid. Objects need key-value pairs.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Of course, it should be an Array.....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `Array.from` method or `spread syntax`.

```js
const state =  new Set( [5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 45, 60] );
console.log(Array.from(state));
console.log([...state]);
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I exactly needed!